# How can I stop my div from scrolling?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, overflow

I have a responsive div that has 6 options (5 blocks of text and 1 button). When this div gets to the mobile phone screen size, the div gains a slight `15px` scroll to it. I am using a lot of `absolute` and `relative` positioning and believe that may be my issue, but I still can't figure it out.

I've tried using a bunch of combinations of `overflow` and `overflow-y`, but can't get it.

HTML:

```
<div class="about-preface">
    <div class="preface-container">
        <div class="preface-block">
            <h4><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i> Donor Acquisition</h4>
            <p>Startup nonprofits and established organizations need to consistently add new donors in order to surpass fundraising goals.</p>
            <p><a href="/about-fundraising-400#a">More on Donor Acquisition</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 more of these divs -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ns89wwzy/) with everything in it as well.

Comment: i can't really see what you are talking about in the fiddle, but you do have your li's with a fixed height, which they will retain even in mobile mode. Are you trying to get it fixed within the mobile viewport? in that case I think % might be better possibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to put `overflow: hidden` on the body to force it to contain the padding you have on `.about-preface`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ns89wwzy/2/)**